# paytabs .aar file dependencies in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':flutter_paytabs_sdk:bundleDebugAar'.

> Direct local .aar file dependencies are not supported when building an
> AAR. The resulting AAR would be broken because the classes and Android
> resources from any local .aar file dependencies would not be packaged
> in the resulting AAR. Previous versions of the Android Gradle Plugin
> produce broken AARs in this case too (despite not throwing this
> error). The following direct local .aar file dependencies of the
> :flutter_paytabs_sdk project caused this error:
> C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartling.org\flutter_paytabs_sdk-1.0.1\android\paytabs_sdk-v4.0.1\paytabs_sdk-v4.0.1.aar

when I install this package `flutter_paytabs_sdk: ^1.0.1`, I face this problem when I run the application again.

I use `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use there new flutter package

```
dependencies:
  flutter_paytabs_bridge: ^2.4.4
```

for more info visit  [flutter_paytabs_bridge](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_paytabs_bridge)